# Create table and copy data from a CSV file

Tags: python, postgresql, psycopg2

I'm using psycopg2 to work with PostgreSQL in Python , i'm using this functionnality to copy data from a CSV file and import it to my database

```
with open(csvFile, 'r') as f:
    next(f) # Skip the header row.
    cur.copy_from(f,table, sep=',')
```

The problem with this is that the table needs to be created before means knowing the content of the file . is there a way to create a table in postgreSQL from a CSV file ? in other word convert a CSV file to a table

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes. U can convert CSV file into table. We can achieve these using pandas.

```
with open(file_input.name, encoding='utf-8-sig', errors='ignore') as csv_obj:
                            csv_dataframe = pd.read_csv(csv_obj)
                            csv_dataframe.to_sql( "table_name"+ str(os.path.splitext(os.path.join(store_path,
                            file.filename))).split(os.sep)[-1], engine, if_exists='replace')
```

In the above code,
Added encoding as utf-8-sig this is for large csv file which has thounds of records. utf-8 working for small csv files.
After this read this object using pandas.
Pandas Dataframe has to_sql method which helps to create csv to table in one liner. Where we pass some parameter. Like table_name and engine name. Here engine I passed sqlalchemy engine.